# AsyncTask publishProgress not updating on onProgressUpdate when using BufferedReader

Tags: android, android-asynctask, bufferedreader, async-onprogressupdate

I want to update download progress of progress dialog but AsyncTask getting hangs when using **`BufferedReader`**. Not calling **`publishProgress`** and not updating progress dialog in **`onProgressUpdate`**. Also, it's not printing Log into while loop.

I have tested using printing Log in my code.

- First Log is printing in `LogCat`
- Second Log is not printing
- The Third Log also not printing and not executing method
  **`publishProgress`**.

  ```
  private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
      private ProgressDialog dialog;
      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();

          dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeScreen.this);
          dialog.setTitle("Be Patient");
          dialog.setMessage("Loading data for first time use only. Please don't close the application.");
          dialog.setCancelable(false);
          dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
          dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
          dialog.show();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
          super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

          dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
          dialog.setMax(100);
          dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

          String serverResponse = null;
          BufferedReader in = null;
          java.net.URL myLink;

          try {
              Log.e("AsyncTask", "This log is printing");
              myLink = new java.net.URL(params[0]);
              in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myLink.openStream()));
              Log.e("AsyncTask", "This log not printing");
              String inputLine;
              StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
              while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                  response.append(inputLine);
                  publishProgress(50);  // Not executing : Default value set is 50 just for cheecking.
                  Log.d("AsyncTask", "This log also not printing & publishProgress not executing");
              }
              serverResponse = response.toString();

          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
              try {
                  if (in != null) in.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
          return serverResponse;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          super.onPostExecute(result);

          if (!HomeScreen.this.isFinishing() && dialog != null) {
              dialog.dismiss();
          }
      }
  }
  ```